# Need help in image upload django form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

I have pulled last uploaded image using following code

```
class categoryForm(forms.Form):
   name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'box'}),max_length=32,label='Category',required=True)
   is_active = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
   id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,required=False)
   photo = forms.ImageField(
     required=False,
     label='Upload photo',
     initial=True,
     help_text='max. 4 megabytes'
     )
   def __init__(self, data,**kwargs):
     super(categoryForm, self).__init__(data, **kwargs)
      if self.data['photo']!='':
         self.fields['photo'].initial=self.data['photo']
```

I have passed data while populating update form

```
p=Category.objects.get(id='%s'%(target_id))
formdata = categoryForm({'name':p.name,'is_active':p.is_active,'id':p.id,'photo':p.image()})
```

It is perfectly showing initial image

Since i have FileField also , i need to pass extra parameter in action page where categoryForm is called i.e

```
formdata = categoryForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
```

This extra parameter is giving me  error below

```
__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

If i remove request.FILES **init**() work fine but i cannot upload image :)

Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does changing the `__init__` function to this help?

```
  def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
     super(categoryForm, self).__init__(data, **kwargs)
      if self.data['photo']!='':
         self.fields['photo'].initial=self.data['photo']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're code is correct, if you say it works ... then it works.
The error comes from here:

```
   def __init__(self, data,**kwargs):
     super(categoryForm, self).__init__(data, files, **kwargs)
      if self.data['photo']!='':
         self.fields['photo'].initial=self.data['photo']
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
formdata = categoryForm(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(categoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      if self.data['photo']!='':
         self.fields['photo'].initial=self.data['photo']
```